# Emp table help, beginner

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a problem to do with the emp table but i cannot figure it out. The problem is Find all of the employees from the sample emp table where the salary is greater than the average of the losal column in the salgrade table. Use a subquery to accomplish the task.

Comment: This reads like a homework problem and you don't seem to have made any attempts to solve it.  Please at least take a crack at issues and report where you're getting stuck, no one wants to do your homework for you.

Comment: @zzevannn is right .. you tagged oracle and mysql which are different.. do you know what is emp table and do you know how to use subquery?

Comment: Please define emp, losal, salgrade, subquery. Also, did you write ANY code at all ?

Comment: I tried for hours doing all different forms of sub queries, yes I know how to use them I was only stuck on this question for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a query to get the average of `losal` and then either use it directly in the `where` clause with the `all` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   emp
WHERE  salary > ALL (SELECT AVG(losal) FROM salgrade)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, as for everyone else i tried for hours but was putting in the query wrong thanks for the help